# Ruby on Rails - enquiring about passing parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, new-operator

I am creating a simple RoR application where I can create posts and also comment on them.  My thought on how to do this is to have posts and comments be of the same type and utilizing the same MVC except comments have a parent id.  Posts will have a parent id of 0 while comments will have the id of its parents.  I was thinking of when I tried to create a comment, I could just pass in the parent's id to the new method.  This did not work.  Although I got no errors it seems like the @post variable in the new method is not the same @post variable in the create method.  My intuition was that the new method creates a new object then passes the object to the view.  The view then populates the objects parameters and then sends it to the create method and the create method saves the object to the database.  From trial and error this does not seem to be the case unless I am just doing it wrong.  Is there an easier way to get the same functionality I am trying to achieve? or is there a way to get my way to work? any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post your code please, otherwise it's hard to follow what's going on.

Comment: Paragraph breaks are your friend. Please space out your question so it isn't just a block of text and, as Andy asks, show us some code of how you think this would work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you follow the classic ["Build a Blog in 15 minutes"](http://media.rubyonrails.org/video/rails_blog_2.mov) video that shows you how to do this.

Among other things, since a post `has_many :comments` I wouldn't recommend doing what you're proposing.

Comment: I agree.  What you're doing is technically possible, but if you're struggling this much with it, first do it the "normal" way with posts and comments being different, then once it's working, start moving towards your more general approach.